# My program keeps terminating when it shouldn't. Why?

Tags: java

Hey guys I was working on making a number averaging program and I wanted to insert this function that allows the user to enter the letter "y" to run again and do another computation, however, my program shows the terminated message (I'm using Eclipse) after the first computation, even though I want the user to be able to enter the input.
Here is the part of the source code that puzzles me:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("This is an averaging program. How many numbers would you like to average together?");
    int total=input.nextInt();
    int i;
    float sum=0;
    for(i=0; i<total; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter your numbers: ");
        sum += input.nextFloat();
    }
    String y;

    System.out.print("Your average is: " + sum/total + "\n");
    System.out.print("Would you like to do another computation? Type y for yes, or something else for no.");
    y=input.nextLine();
```

Comment: Well, if that's the end of the program, then there's nothing telling it to start over after you answer the prompt.

Comment: It isn't the end of the program, it's part of it. I have it written so that main() says that if the user inputs "y", another function which is identical starts to run, and if the user wants to enter ANOTHER computation, then that function calls itself.

Comment: Ah, so two things: 1) That kind of duplication is terrible. Don't do it. 2) [user000001's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14866999/839646) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is that duplication terrible?

Comment: My answer of course is relevant if OP presses `enter` after entering each number.

Comment: Also, I keep getting an error saying that readLine() isn't part of the Scanner class.

Comment: yes it is `nextLine()`. I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

change

```
sum += input.nextFloat();
```

to

```
sum += input.nextFloat();
input.nextLine();
```

And

```
int total=input.nextInt();
```

to

```
int total=input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
```

Explanation. You should manually read the newline character `\n` after reading a number form `Scanner`

Of course you should also add the relevant part of the program in a `do` `while` loop in order to execute repeatedly, but you probably know that.

Comment: How does this help run the program again if the user answers "y"?

Comment: It doesn't but it does solve the problem of the program prematurely ending instead of waiting for an input.

Comment: The do-while loop....why didn't I think of that! My dad always kept saying use a loop not recursive function but I could never figure it out, I might be able to now. Thanks!